# get vertex world position in glsl

Tags: glsl, vertex-shader

How can I get a vec3 with the the world position of a vertex?

let's say I want to get white pixels for positions of a cube at Y 1 in world space and black pixels for 0…

I tried

(vertex shader)

```
[...]

varying float whiteness;

[...]

vec4 posWorld = gl_ProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
whiteness = clamp(posWorld.y,0.0,1.0);

[...]
```

(fragment shader)

```
[...]

varying float whiteness;

[...]

gl_FragColor.rgb = vec3(whiteness);

[...]
```

But that gives me weird results where the surface still depends on the camera angle and height.

How can I just get the vertex position in world space x,y,z?

Comment: Why would you think that the projection matrix leads to *world space*?

Comment: Heh, because i couldn't find a better matrix. Is there such a thing as WorldMatrix? if I look in the quick reference http://mew.cx/glsl_quickref.pdf I can't find such a thing as a world matrix :/

Answer (score 1):

Read into how points are transformed from their local space into the coordinates of your screen.

```
worldMatrix * vertex = worldSpace

viewMatrix * worldSpace = viewSpace

projectionMatrix * viewSpace = screenSpace
```

You should be passing the World Matrix into the shader and multiplying the vertex by that if you wish to get the position of the vertex.

```
vec4 posWorld = worldMatrix * gl_Vertex;
```

Comment: thanks, but where do I get the world matrix? there doesn't seem to be anything lime gl_WorldMatrix

Comment: if you are simply rendering a model (without translation / rotation / scaling) then your world matrix will simply be the identity matrix and can be left out.

Comment: How about if we are translating and rotating?

Comment: Then the world matrix can be that of the transformation. Look up transformation matrices.